# Fetch data from table by making a comparison between different rows and same Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each row with the same Company and Area Column, if the one of the Investment value is zero then fetch the row, whose investment value is not Zero.

For each row with the same Company and Area Column, if the Investment values are the same then fetch the row, whose True_False value is Zero.

Here is the complete Query which is working fine to get the desired output.

```
create table #tempData(
  Company varchar(max), 
  Area varchar(max),
  investment int, 
  True_False Bit
)

insert into #tempData values('Apple','CA', 5244, 0)
insert into #tempData values('Apple','CA', 5244, 1)
insert into #tempData values('Apple','GA', 5244, 0)
insert into #tempData values('Apple','GA', 0, 1)
insert into #tempData values('HP','NC', 100, 0)
insert into #tempData values('HP','NC', 100, 1)
insert into #tempData values('Lenovo','MN', 0, 0)
insert into #tempData values('Lenovo','MN', 0, 1)
insert into #tempData values('Acer','MN', 0, 0)
insert into #tempData values('Acer','MN', 278, 1)


select * into #tempResult1 from (
  select *, DENSE_RANK() over(order by Company, Area) as Rank_  
  from #tempData  
) a 
where a.True_False = 0

select * into #tempResult2 from (
  select *, DENSE_RANK() over(order by Company, Area) as Rank_  
  from #tempData  
) a where a.True_False= 1

select * 
from  #tempResult1 R1 
join #tempResult2 R2 on R1.Rank_ = R2.Rank_
```

Then:

```
select  R1.* 
from #tempResult1 R1  
join #tempResult2 R2 on R1.Rank_= R2.Rank_  
where R1.investment = R2.Investment 
  and (R1.investment <> 0 or R2.investment <> 0)
union -- UNION 
select R2.* 
from #tempResult1 R1  
join #tempResult2 R2 on R1.Rank_= R2.Rank_  
where R1.investment = 0 and R2.investment <> 0
union -- UNION
select  R1.* 
from #tempResult1 R1  
join #tempResult2 R2 on R1.Rank_ = R2.Rank_  
where R2.investment = 0 and R1.investment <> 0
union - UNION --
select R1.* 
from #tempResult1 R1  
join #tempResult2 R2 on R1.Rank_ = R2.Rank_  
where R2.investment = 0 and R1.investment = 0

--drop table #tempData
--drop table #tempResult1 
--drop table #tempResult2
```

Now the question is I would Like to achieve the same output without using the two temp-Tables that are #tempResult1 and #tempResult2.

**I tried this but is not working**:

```
select * from #tempData t 
 where exists ( select 1 from #tempData t2 where t.Company= t2.Company and t.Area = t2.Area and t.investment =0 and t2.investment <>0  and t2.True_False = 1 )

 union

 select * from #tempData t 
 where exists ( select 1 from #tempData t2 where t.Company= t2.Company and t.Area = t2.Area and t.investment = t2.investment  and t.True_False = 0 )
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use CTEs? They would make your life much easier.

Comment: The simple answer is: use table variables instead. But I guess what you're really asking is how to do it all inline